# Inline Check for IsDbNull in C#

Tags: c#

How can I write the following line:

```
 document.Total = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Total")) == true : 0.0m ? (decimal?)reader["Total"];
```

The error I am getting is that cannot convert type from bool to decimal?

Answer (score 4):

You accidentally flipped the `?` and `:`.  It should be:

```
document.Total = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Total")) == true ? 0.0m : (decimal?)reader["Total"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a shorter way to handle `DBNull.Value` and DataReaders.

Consider using

```
document.Total = (reader["Total"] as decimal?) ?? 0.0m;
```